# Rails preloading the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having trouble preloading a `belongs_to` association.

The model in question has following association

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_name, -> { select(:id, :name) }, class_name: "User", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

The above association works fine and resolves as expected.

I want to return the `user.id` and `user.name` along with `order`. 
How do I preload the association `user_name`.

I did try `Order.includes(:user_name)`, which did not work as expected.

Comment: This looks strange, why don't you just do `belongs_to :user` and then `Order.find(1).user.name`?

Comment: You should't select in relationship. You can add a scope in the model

Comment: What exactly didnt work with `Order.includes(:user_name)`?

Answer (score 1):

I would change association just to:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and select `users.id` and `users.name` elsewhere. It makes your code more flexible.

---

> How do I preload the association

`ActiveRecord` provides a few ways for that:

1. [Preload](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload). Loads the association data in a separate query. Since
   preload always generates two sql you can not use preloaded table in
   where condition.
2. [Includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes). By default loads the association data in
   a separate query just like preload. But with additional [references](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references)
   call it switches from using two separate queries to creating a
   single `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. So with that you can use association tables in where condition.
3. [Eager load](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load). Loads association in a single query using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Here is some useful articles:

[Preload, Eagerload, Includes and Joins](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html)

[Making sense of ActiveRecord joins, includes, preload, and eager_load](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a scope like below

```
scope : user_name_id, -> { joins(:user_name).select( 'user_names.id, user_names.name' ).collect{|c| [c.id, c.name]} }
```